# Flask Live HLS Streaming with GStreamer only works on the local machine

Tags: flask, gstreamer, http-live-streaming, video.js

I know this might be a dumb question but I could find a answer anywhere

So, what I am trying to accomplish is a simple HLS live stream using Gstreamer and Flask.

When I test it on my machine locally, it works as expected (shows the camera feed), but when I try and access it through another machine on my local network it doesn't.

I use video.js to show the stream on the HTML page

Here is the Gstreamer command:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device="/dev/video0" ! videoconvert ! clockoverlay ! x264enc tune=zerolatency ! mpegtsmux ! hlssink playlist-root=http://0.0.0.0:8080 target-duration=1 max-files=5
```

This is the Python code:

```
from flask import render_template, Blueprint, send_from_directory

hain = Blueprint('main',__name__)

@hain.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@hain.route('/<string:file_name>')
def stream(file_name):
    video_dir = './Hain/video'
    return send_from_directory(directory=video_dir, filename=file_name)
```

And this is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Test</title>
      <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/6.2.8/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Video feed tester</h1>
      <video id="player" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload>
         <source src="http://0.0.0.0:8080/playlist.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL">
      </video>
      <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/6.2.8/video.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/videojs-contrib-hls/5.12.2/videojs-contrib-hls.min.js"></script>
      <script>
          var player = videojs('player', {width: 350, height: 200});
          player.play();
     </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

What could the problem be?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you edit your question to specify how exactly you run your app from a different machine? Also, what happens when it fails -- are there any errors in the browser console? From the first glance, you are using a localhost IP address in the `<source>` tag which probably causes the issue. It would make the browser request a livestream from a machine that is running the browser. It should be either an IP address that is accessible through the network, or a domain name.

Comment: By running on another machine, I mean open it from the browser, using the local IP address

Comment: Could you open the web inspector in your browser and take a look at all the HTTP requests it makes? There's probably one that fails, and it is probably knocking on `localhost:8080`. This would likely be what you want to change.

Comment: thanks, I'm kinda new in dev in general and I've should've known that it wouldn't work with 0.0.0.0.

Changing it to my local network IP address resolved the issue and works like a charm on all devices.

Comment: Also like to state that the flask send_from_directory() function didn't work until I used an absolute directory... os.path.abspath(my_relative_video_path)